# React Contexts for State Management

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a UserContext and a SocketContext (socket.io) that need to be access by multiple components. Some of these components need to use both of these contexts and force me to use the Consumer and pass values in as props instead of using contextType.

Is it good practice to create a GlobalContext that contains both the user and socket object? I have looked into React hooks which have useContext. Should I use this instead?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is good idea to keep contexts apart. When context is changed, components which consume it will be probably re-render. If you're going to use `useContext` hook, there are 3 [recommended solutions](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693) on how to keep components from frequent updates when context changes. First solution suggests to split contexts.

Even if you will not use `useContext`, frequent re-rendering may become problem with single context. So it is possible to consume [multiple context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts).

And suggested solution for several context values, changing together.

> If two or more context values are often used together, you might want to consider creating your own render prop component that provides both.